# Wix bundle uninstall display msi uninstall

Tags: wix

I have a wix bundle that install IIS, postgresql and a MyApp.msi file created by a separate wix installer.

When uninstalling the .msi file I have a custom action which is executed on uninstall. The purpose of the feature is to ask the user whether he wants to delete the database or not.

```
<Custom Action="DropDatabaseAndDeleteFolder" After="RemoveFiles"> (REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
```

And this works well.

However when uninstalling the bundle from Programs and Features the .msi uninstall window is not displayed and thus the action above will not be executed.

Is it possible when uninstalling the bundle to also display the .msi uninstall window which will allow to run the defined custom actions?

Thanks

Comment: Is this custom action located only in the GUI sequence? In your compiled MSI that would be the `InstallUISequence table`. If the setup is run in silent mode, then the whole `InstallUISequence` is skipped, causing all custom actions that only exist there (and not in the `InstallExecuteSequence`) to never be run. Also: I would think hard if this feature is really necessary: a database is user data, and I don't like to delete data automatically - any bugs in your custom action could cause serious problems (and such bugs do happen).